# APL: array's element replacement and multiplication

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, apl, dyalog, array-replace

Let's say in APL language, I have a 2D array of shape 10x3. I cannot figure it out how to:
replace all the occurrence of some specific numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) in the entire array with 0, 10, 100, 1000 respectively. So I want to map 1 to 0, 2 to 10, 3 to 100 and 4 to 1000 in the entire array.

Comment: It would be useful to know which implementation and version of APL you are using.

Comment: dyalog 18.0.38756

Comment: Do you know any tutorial that shows manipulation of APL built in functions  with 3d? MasteringDyalogAPL.pdf is not covering 3d a lot.

Comment: Should really be a separate questions, but have a look at the three webinars [here](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Dyalog_webinar#2020) that have "rank operator" in their title, and/or SP2 [here](https://www.dyalog.com/user-meetings/dyalog19.htm#SP02).

Comment: Thank you so much Adam

Comment: You're very welcome. Also, consider dropping by [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) when you have a question that is too small/specific/embarrassing/… for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

I'll be using this example data:

```apl
      ⎕ ← array ← ? 10 3 ⍴ 10
 5  7  8
10  2 10
 9  8 10
 3  5  4
 6  6  4
 2  9  7
 4  5 10
 1  9  4
 1 10  1
10  5  3
      specific ← 1 2 3 4
      replacements ← 0 10 100 1000
```

Let's define a helper function to identify occurrences of elements that need to be mapped, namely those that are **members of** our list of specific numbers:

```apl
      Occurrences ← {⍵ ∊ specific}
      Occurrences array
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 1
0 0 1
```

Next, we define a mapping function that looks up the **index of** each element in the set of specific numbers, and uses those indices to **index into** the replacements:

```apl
      Map ← {replacements[specific ⍳ ⍵]}
      Map 3 1 4 1
100 0 1000 0
```

Now we can apply the mapping function **at** the occurrences:

```apl
      Map @ Occurrences array
   5  7    8
  10 10   10
   9  8   10
 100  5 1000
   6  6 1000
  10  9    7
1000  5   10
   0  9 1000
   0 10    0
  10  5  100
```

We can define the whole thing as a single replacement function:

```apl
      Replace ← Map @ Occurrences
```

Or even go directly for the full definition without the helper functions:

```apl
      Replace ← {replacements[specific ⍳ ⍵]} @ {⍵ ∊ specific}
```

The resulting definition will be the same: <sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVIVHbRMUEouKEivBLHsFQwMFY4VHvVuADK7igtTkzLTMZLCUoYIRUMaEqyi1ICcxOTU3Na@kGCxhANJjaADGBlxcMEOrkRVGI4zq3QzEW2NrFRwUqoEMhUcdXQow2VqIU/7/BwA)</sup>

```apl
      Replace array
   5  7    8
  10 10   10
   9  8   10
 100  5 1000
   6  6 1000
  10  9    7
1000  5   10
   0  9 1000
   0 10    0
  10  5  100
```

We can even define a general-purpose replacement operator: <sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVIVHbRMUEouKEivBLHsFQwMFY4VHvVuADK7igtTkzLTMZLCUoYIRUMaEqyi1ICcxOTU3Na@kGCxhANJjaADGBlxc8UEQBfFgyepHvbuASEEDaOZWIFJ41LP9Ue@KRx0zHnU1AcU2K2gqOIBkO7pAYhDFmiDFtVww52nA3YEwG9kVmhAP/P8PAA)</sup>

```apl
      _Replace_ ← {⍺⍺ ( ⍵⍵ ⌷⍨∘⊂ ⍳ ) @ ( ∊∘⍺⍺ ) ⍵}
      (specific _Replace_ replacements) array
   5  7    8
  10 10   10
   9  8   10
 100  5 1000
   6  6 1000
  10  9    7
1000  5   10
   0  9 1000
   0 10    0
  10  5  100
```

This operator definition can be found in [APLcart](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/APLcart) with [a query like *search and replace elements*](https://aplcart.info/?q=search%20and%20replace%20elements#).

---

Consider using a mathematical relationship between the specific values and the replacement values, rather than doing a lookup:

```apl
      ( 1 ≠ specific ) × 10 * specific - 1
0 10 100 1000
```

Now we can write: <sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVIVHbRMUEouKEivBLHsFQwMFY4VHvVuADK7igtTkzLTMZLCUoYIRUMaEiwumq1oDKPaocwFQ9VYFTYXD00F6tcA8XQXDWgUHhWoQ@1FHlwLMoFqIVf//AwA)</sup>

```apl
      {( 1 ≠ ⍵ ) × 10 * ⍵ - 1} @ {⍵ ∊ specific} array
   5  7    8
  10 10   10
   9  8   10
 100  5 1000
   6  6 1000
  10  9    7
1000  5   10
   0  9 1000
   0 10    0
  10  5  100
```